# I have upgraded new apk over old application

Tags: android, apk, keystore

I have uploaded new apk over old application using old keystore. but the problem is that it shows the "in prod" in status field and also shows uploaded date of old build uploaded. but version is shown right which i have changed. please suggest what is the problem...

Thanks,
Jeetendra

Comment: are you sure its published??

Comment: i guess old version has to be archived before new version gets published. check if its really published